# Why can I not use a custom type from another variable in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a variable in unity called *"rarity"* and its type is *"rarity"* in this format:

```
public rarity rarity
```

For some reason I can't use this same type in another script. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You'd need to show the definition of rarity..., most likely its private to the class its in

Answer (score 0):

I quickly realized I needed to derive from MonoBehaviour and use the namespace. Sorry about that!

Comment: Well to declare a variable it doesnt have to be a monobehavior so this answer would be incorrect, you wouldnt be able to add your script to a game object because its not monobehavior...